Mono C#, SendMessage does not fired or WndProc can not catch
I tried to send a message in the thread environment to main handle window. but does not fired or can not catch the specified event messages at all.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, IntPtr lParam);

SendMessage(mainHandle, WM_SENSOR_EVENT_MESSAGE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

and Main Form is used WndProc(ref Message m), but can not catch the any message from thread. All testing is works fine on windows environment but Mono on linux. thanks in advance.
Cheers.
HS
